# How can I hide the address bar in a modal dialog?

Tags: javascript

How can I hide the address bar (location bar ) in a modal dialog?
Here is my code:

```
var dialogFeatures = 'center:yes; dialogWidth:600px; location:no;dialogHeight:400px; edge:raised; help:no; resizable:no; scroll:no; status:no; statusbar:no; toolbar:no; menubar:no; addressbar:no; titlebar:no;';
newwindow2 = window.showModalDialog('Combo?start1=' + calEvent.start + '&end1=' + calEvent.end + '&ownerType=' + < %= ApplicationConstants.OWNER_TYPE_CALENDAR % > , 'app', dialogFeatures);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not possible. The address bar is a security feature in most browsers, in IE since version 7, in Firefox (I think) since version 2.

Comment: @pavan edited - it really applies to most browsers these days

Comment: any option for modal feature on window.open

Comment: @pavan `window.open` works the same way, you will always have an address bar.

Comment: i hv another doubt..how to refresh parent window,ven u closing popup

Comment: @pavan re jQuery popup though, yes, JQuery UI Modal dialog will work

Comment: how can i pass my servlet call to jquery modal dialog

Comment: In showmodaldialog i pass servlet call as a one parameter...in jquery modal how?

Comment: pls stop ignoring everything you are told

Comment: @Pekka: +1 for the ordeal you've had to go through.

Comment: @Andy thanks! If this were my day job and I *had* to do it, I would be weeping by now, and/or seriously thinking about quitting :D

Comment: But because we volunteer we're willing to put up with more crap? :P

Comment: @Roger Pate somehow, magically, yes! :D Jeff Atwood's thought this through very well.

Comment: It's quite the paradox in which I fear I'll forever participate and never understand.

Answer (score 2):

You can't hide the address bar, `location: no` is not a valid option for the `features` argument.

In Internet Explorer 7 and later, all windows opened by the browser have an address bar.  The same is true of Google Chrome and other browsers supporting `showModalDialog`.

Comment: @Andy this answer was clearly not satisfactory, which is why the OP chose to [ask it again](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164824/how-to-hide-address-bar-on-showmodaldialog/4164844#4164844). He got the same answer there, we'll see whether he'll open another one

Comment: @Pekka: he could have at least copy and pasted the improved grammar/formatting from here!

Comment: @Andy read the comments underneath my answer there. I've never seen anything so bizarre on SO

Comment: @Pekka - Yep, [there's another one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164824/how-to-hide-address-bar-on-showmodaldialog-closed).

Comment: @Nick yeah, we were just merged from there :)

Comment: @Nick I think so, too. Looks like an incurable help vampire

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

Hiding the address bar is disallowed in most browsers, for security reasons.

Answer (score -1):

in about:config change this parameter:

**dom.disable_window_open_feature.location**

and for menubar and any other components you have to change their feature in about:config