# How to hide address bar on showmodaldialog

Tags: javascript, javascript-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I hide the address bar in a modal dialog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4164626/how-can-i-hide-the-address-bar-in-a-modal-dialog)

hello guys,

how to hide address bar (location bar ) on showmodaldialog..
code:

```
                           var dialogFeatures = 'center:yes; dialogWidth:600px; location:no;dialogHeight:400px; edge:raised; help:no; resizable:no; scroll:no; status:no; statusbar:no; toolbar:no; menubar:no; addressbar:no; titlebar:no;';
                            newwindow2=window.showModalDialog('Combo?start1='+calEvent.start+'&end1='+calEvent.end+'&ownerType='+<%= ApplicationConstants.OWNER_TYPE_CALENDAR %>,'app',dialogFeatures);
```